# How do I configure Nginx to be a forward proxy which requires a username and password?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, proxy

Right now I have a proxy set up at MyDomain.com:8080, but I'd like to have it secured.

To get this proxy setup I added this to my nginx config file:

```
server {
    listen       8080;

    location / {
        resolver 8.8.8.8;
        proxy_pass http://$http_host$uri$is_args$args;
    }
```

I tried searching but only came up with results for a /reverse/ proxy. I need a regular one.

Answer (score 1):

nginx makes a great reverse proxy, but is less than ideal as a forward proxy. [It can be done](http://ef.gy/xhtml/using-nginx-as-a-proxy-server), but since writing the rules you want will be rather hairy, you're almost certainly better off to use a purpose-built forward proxy, such as squid. Doing so also means your future self will have a much better chance of understanding what's going on when trying to maintain or debug the proxy.

Comment: It works as a forward proxy, what's wrong with using it as one?

Comment: If that were actually true, there would be nothing wrong with it.

Comment: It /is/ true! I have a proxy setup on my VPS using only Nginx at this very moment. I used parts of [this](http://ef.gy/using-nginx-as-a-proxy-server). I only need to make it so that it requires a username and password.